# Should I be able to downvote my own question to help the community to rid the Internet of it if it is bad?

Tags: feature-request

When I ask a question and it gets downvotes because it is a bad question, should I be able to join into the poo slinging match and downvote my own question? Logically I should be able to as a good citizen. Upvoting my own question would be unfair of course, but downvoting is completely different.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This question was about the questions which can't be deleted any more by their OP, and not from any posts in general. The difference is significant, and having a golden tag badge you should understand it pretty well.

Comment: @peterh the difference is not significant enough to  justify a separate request. If the team will decide to go this direction, they can easily add such a condition (self downvote only on posts that can't be deleted) and mention this in the official answer.

Comment: Who the f edited the title and completely buggered the meaning of the question??? It had NOTHING to do with "Can't be deleted"!!!

Comment: @ajeh You can see who edited it in the revision history, which is also where you can roll back changes you don't feel were appropriate.

Comment: This was rather a [rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question).

Answer (score 3):

If you realize that your question is a bad question, you can simply delete it.  (Or better yet, edit it such that it's no longer a low quality question.)  There's no need for you to be able to downvote it.

Comment: Unless it's answered and that answer has a positive score...

Comment: Then flag for a moderator to delete it for you (plus the reason why)

Comment: @peterh Why? The comment is 100% correct.  Wouldn't it be easier to just improve the quality of the question instead of contributing to your eventual question ban?

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe you should read once more what you react. This post is from the undeletable, downvoted questions.

Comment: That undeleteable question can be improved; the comment is also correct and promotes positive behavior within the community not negative behavior like downvoting your own question

Comment: @peterh The OP specified no such thing.  Someone else went and edited that in after the fact, despite the question *actually* being about *all* questions.

Comment: @Servy But why should I delete the question? If this was a bad question, the whole world should know about that! Otherwise why allowing downvotes on the questions then? The whole purpose of downvoting questions is to let the world know that an anonymous crowd agreed it was a bad question. At some point the OP might realize that as well and wnat to join in to slug the bad question even further.

Comment: @ajeh Why should you delete it, because it's not helpful.  Yes, downvotes exist to inform people that the question isn't worth their time *so they don't need to bother looking at it*.  Deleting it does the same thing *even better* because they don't even need to look at a question with a low score to realize it's not worth their time, they just don't see it.

Comment: Then let anyone delete any question, answer or comment!

Comment: @ajeh People *can* delete any answer, question, or comment, so long as they have earned sufficient reputation to have the relevant permission, and enough other users agree with them (how many others will vary based on context).  There are also of course systems in place to prevent abuse or deletion of content others consider valuable.

Comment: Then the system is already perfect. Which is pretty obvious from the fact that this question has been downvoted. I agree now that this is a bad question, but can't add to the dismay of the public about it. Oh, I guess the system is not that perfect, because now I am not happy because I cannot express how much I agree with 3 million lemmings.